# Text animation before it disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made animations for text to show and hide, but I don't know how to make it work correctly. Please help.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

My English is bad, so this is written by a google translatorㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

I want that when a button is pressed, a specific text with animation is shown, and another is hiding, and also when the “hide” button is pressed, the text is hiding, also with animation. The problem is that the text hiding without animation, I just don’t know how to attach it.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

```js
function hide(Id) {
  document.getElementById(Id).style.display = "none";
}

function show(Id) {
  document.getElementById(Id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
p {text-align: center;
}
@keyframes text-fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-10vw);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0vw);
  }
}

.text-fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: text-fade-in;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-timing-function: easeOutCirc;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes text-fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0vw);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-10vw);
  }
}

.text-fade-out {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: text-fade-out;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-timing-function: easeOutCirc;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show('Text1'); hide('Text2'); hide('Text3')">Text1</button>

<button onclick="show('Text2'); hide('Text1'); hide('Text3')">Text2</button>

<button onclick="show('Text3'); hide('Text1'); hide('Text2')">Text3</button>

<button onclick="hide('Text1'); hide('Text2'); hide('Text3')">Hide </button>

<p class="text-fade-in" id="Text1" style="display:none">Text1</p>

<p class="text-fade-in" id="Text2" style="display:none">Text2</p>

<p class="text-fade-in" id="Text3" style="display:none">Text3</p>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you want the code to do?

Comment: In what way does it *not* "work correctly"?  Can you update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example?

Comment: @Tim

I added a description

Comment: reproduce the codepen - https://codepen.io/BHANUHANSA-RATH/pen/xxMozoR what's wrong in it. It's working fine

Comment: @David
I added a description

Comment: @Rakesh 
The problem is that the text disappears without animation, I just don’t know how to attach it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about this functionality.

Just check it and tell me your thought

I am also adding a [codepen](https://codepen.io/BHANUHANSA-RATH/pen/xxMozoR?editors=0011)

```js
let p = document.querySelectorAll("p");


for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  p[i].addEventListener("animationend", function () {
    if (
      p[i].style.display !== "none" &&
      [...p[i].classList].includes("text-fade-out")
    ) {
      p[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}

let isClearTimeout = false;
 function show(Id) {
  let ce = document.getElementById(Id);
  let ad = 0;
  if(ce.style.display !== 'none') return;

 
  Array.from(p).forEach((el) => {
    if (el.style.display !== "none") {
      hide();
      ad = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(el).animationDuration) * 1000;
    }
  });
  if(isClearTimeout){
    clearTimeout(isClearTimeout)
  }
  isClearTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    if (ce.style.display === "none") {
      ce.classList.remove("text-fade-out");
      ce.style.display = "block";
      ce.classList.add("text-fade-in");
    }
  }, ad);
}

function hide() {
  // let ce = document.getElementById(Id);
  
  
  Array.from(p).forEach((ce)=>{
    if (ce.style.display === "block") {
    ce.classList.remove("text-fade-in");

    ce.classList.add("text-fade-out");
  }
  })
}
```

```css
 @keyframes text-fade-in {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-10vw);
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0vw);
      }
    }
    .text-fade-in {
      opacity: 0;
      animation-name: text-fade-in;
/*       animation-delay: 0.4s; */
      animation-duration: 0.4s;
      animation-timing-function: easeOutCirc;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes text-fade-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0vw);
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-10vw);
      }
    }
    .text-fade-out {
      opacity: 1;
      animation-name: text-fade-out;
/*       animation-delay: 0.4s; */
      animation-duration: 0.4s;
      animation-timing-function: easeOutCirc;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="show('Text1')">Text1</button>
  <button onclick="show('Text2')">Text2</button>
  <button onclick="show('Text3')">Text3</button>
  <button onclick="hide()">Hide all</button>

  <p class="text-fade-in" id="Text1" style="display:none" >Text1</p>
  <p class="text-fade-in" id="Text2" style="display:none" >Text2</p>
  <p class="text-fade-in" id="Text3" style="display:none" >Text3</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Amazing! 
The only request is that the text remains in place when the same button is pressed again.

Comment: You Just need to add this single line ``` if(ce.style.display !== 'none') return;
```

Comment: editted the snippet

Comment: Oh, I see you added it to Codepen. Thank you very much for your help! 
I suffered with this problem for too long, but you saved me. Thanks again!

Comment: Unnecessary self-promotion is a great way to get your answers deleted as spam. See [how to not be a spammer](/help/promotion). These links should be included in your profile, not your answers.

Comment: @Rakesh I know that I already ask for too much, but I ask you to help me for the last time, I need that when clicking on the button there is a text <pre> with animation and <h1> without animation appear, and when you press another button, <pre> also disappear with animation, and <h1> without, and appears another <pre> and <h1>, and only <h1> in last case . https://codepen.io/mogire7144/pen/QWYXVzO

Comment: @Rakesh I made it, but can you please make it so that there is no need to indicate each id for each ` h1`. https://codepen.io/mogire7144/pen/KKJjYgW

Comment: @Rakesh Nevermind, that's done too.

Comment: okay fine ......

Answer (score 1):

One issue that I see is that you can't animate the display property. I see that you have an opacity set using CSS, but setting the display to none in your `onclick` handler would negate that.

I modified your code to produce some transitions based on what I am guessing that you are attempting to do.

```js
const mainButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const text1 = document.querySelector('#Text1')
const text2 = document.querySelector('#Text2')
const text3 = document.querySelector('#Text3')
const hideAll = document.querySelector('.hide-all')
const allText = document.querySelectorAll('p')

mainButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    switch(index) {
      case 0:
        text1.style.left = "0"
        break;
      case 1:
        text2.style.left = "0"
        break;
      case 2:
        text3.style.left = "0"
    }
  })
})

hideAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
  allText.forEach((text) => {
    text.style.left = "-100%";
  })
})
```

```css
.text-container {
  position: relative;
}

#Text1 {
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#Text2 {
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#Text3 {
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>Text1</button>
<button class='btn'>Text2</button>
<button class='btn'>Text3</button>
<button class='hide-all'>Hide all</button>
    
<div class="text-container">
  <p class="text-fade-in" id = "Text1">Text1</p>
  <p class="text-fade-in" id = "Text2">Text2</p>
  <p class="text-fade-in" id = "Text3">Text3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this, just don't know how to make it differently

Comment: I edited my comment to add a snippet that will hopefully help you out.

Comment: Thank you, that’s almost what I need, the only things left is that when you click on a button with one text, the rest is hiding, and so that the text is on the same level

Comment: You could add a property of `display:flex` to the text's container which would make the text sit on a single row. I'm not sure if you need the text to be fluid, such that it can move text or be moved by other text when coming into view. That would be a more complicated addition that I'm honestly not sure how to do off the top of my head.

Comment: Ideally, when I click on the "Text1" button, the Text1 should smoothly appear, moving towards the center of the screen and after this when I, for example, click "Text2", Text1 should also smoothly disappear in the direction of the appearing Text2

Comment: Text2 should also replace Text1 position